# Inputting bulk logs in Logstash (stored in different folders) using the "file" plugin without specifying individual filters

Tags: logstash

So I have a question about the basic functionality of logstash. I have many different .L01 files which I have exported into log files. Each .L01 file represents a host and the export function dumps it into a folder-tree. I need to read the logs from these individual "host folders" including all the different sub-folders. To manually add the path of each input log is obviously not feasible. The files are all different types of logs, so I can't define a standard filter for them. If I just run logstash without defining any filters, it just dumps the whole log in the @message field like this:

```
   "message" => "6.703: Destination:C:\\WINDOWS\\INF\\inetres.adm \r",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-07-18T00:42:32.544Z",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "host_1"
],
      "host" => "<hostname>",
      "path" => "<whatever the path is>"
```

So how do I configure logstash if I essentially need to read all logs generated on a computer (so naturally different types of logs) but from a folder (so can't use input plugins like syslog). Do I need to write individual filters for every single kind of log? That would need me to manually parse through all the folders and subfolders and then write a filter for each log after examining the content. I don't think I can do that because I need to do this for approximately 20 hosts. I would appreciate any help towards this.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple paths in the file input

[logstash / inputs / file](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file)

> path (required setting)
>
> Value type is array
>
> There is no default value for this setting.
>
> You may also configure multiple paths. See an example on the Logstash configuration page.

If you need to specify to look into subdirectories, you can utilize /**/ to specify to go a level deeper.

I hope that helps clarify things.